# How to connect WPF(C#) app to a Node.js API route?

Tags: c#, node.js, .net, wpf

So I have a WPF application that I want to connect to a RESTful API made with Node.js express server, I have the API on my local pc and the WPF app as well and I want to connect the WPF app to a route in the API called "meals", is there a way to do that?

Comment: Of course there's a way :) but let's see what you have tried first. We can't give you a solution without knowing some of your code base

Comment: @Xerillio oh thank you, but my problem is solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a way to do that

the below code sends a post and a get requests to the API just change the `port` to whatever port you're running your API on

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

public async void SendPostRequestToAPI(){

        // POST REQUEST
        try
        {
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
               { "thing1", "hello" },
               { "thing2", "world" }
            };
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

            var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:port", content);

            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + ex.StackTrace);
        }

        // GET REQUEST
        try
        {
            var responseString = await client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:port");
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error..... " + ex.StackTrace);
        }
}
```

don't forget to use the following directive

```
using System.Net.Http;
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, appreciate it